# Magento Dependency Custom Form

Tags: php, xml, magento

I am new to magento and am working in making some updates to a module.
As far as I've seen all form configuration for admin is done through system.xml, I need to add some sort of dependency as I want my form to check for some api credentials if they are correct show some other inputs.
I've tried with depends tag but am not being able to call a function from there.

So I have two questions:
How do I manage to make dependency when it depends on a value I do not know unless i consult for example an api, can I do something like:

```
<usertoken translate="label">
    <label>User Token</label>
    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
    <sort_order>1</sort_order>
    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
</usertoken>
<new_value translate="label">
    <label>New Value</label>
    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
    <sort_order>1</sort_order>
    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
    <depends><usertoken><action>mymodule/system_config_source_token/retorno</action></usertoken></depends>
</new_value>
```

If so, what should I use instead of action.

My seccond question is, is there any other way to construct a form in admin panel than using system.xml, I would like to create my own custom forms, using ajax, tables with checkboxes.... but would like to understand how can I integrate that.

Comment: Stackoverflow works best with asking one question at a time. And as your questions are specific to Magento, I suggest to consider posting on the Magento Stackexchange instead: http://magento.stackexchange.com/ - and for which XML elements are available and how they work you can find out ultimatively by reading the source-code of magento. If you don't want to do that, don't ask in this way but instead provide reference to a way how it works and then ask if it does not work because you expected it to wrok. But unless, either check the source or consult support.

Answer (score 0):

> is there any other way to construct a form in admin panel than using system.xml, I would like to create my own custom forms, using ajax, tables with checkboxes.... but would like to understand how can I integrate that.

Yes there is. Magento is quite modular, and all you see in the XML configuration has a counterpart in PHP code. Most of the PHP code you can extend in your own modules.

You integrate best by using a step debugger and locate the functionality in core magento. Then consider one of the many ways on how to extend magento to apply / inject the changes you're looking for.
´
In your case you're also probably asking the wrong question. A configuration value does not depend on another one. It's either there or not and the code you produce shouldn't be searching for something but just ask for the information it needs to run. That should keep the overall logic less complex = less bugs.

The correct question back could be: Why is the dependency within configuration and not within the code?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a dependency for system configuration fields by declaring an observer on the *adminhtml_init_system_config* event. This will let you modify the xml declared tabs, groups, fields of the system.xml of all modules. The observer method will look like the following:

```
    public function initSystemConfig($observer){
        $config = $observer->getConfig();
        $paymentGroups = $config->getNode('sections/payment/groups');
        //modify the payment groups array here...
```

This [page](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method) has a tutorial on Magento events and how to hook into them.